# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - Install and use Gedmo

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, timestamp, zend-framework2, zend-db

I found the Gidmo extension which eg provides a timestamp function for creation and update of objects.

Thats what I (and oddly enough nobody else from the Zend guys) need!

I tried including the namespace via `use` like it is shown [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md). But no success. The Doctrine validation returns valid and no errors elsewhere but when creating a new object, the `created_at` attribute is empty.

I also tried [this approach](http://juriansluiman.nl/nl/article/116/use-the-gedmo-doctrine-extensions-in-zend-framework-2) but same result.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master"
```

Entity.php:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
...

class Entity {   

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"timestamp"})
 * @Form\Options({"label":"Created at"})
 * @Form\Exclude()
 *
 */
protected $created_at;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you really need an extension for achieving the functionality you're seeking,have a look over the @Version annotation discussed within this section: [Optimistic Locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) of the Doctrine Documentation.

[EDIT] The @Version is available (as well as all Doctrine ORM mapping annotations) under the namespace `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping`

Usage for a timestamp field : `@Version @ORM\Column(type="datetime")`

Usage for an integer field : `@Version @Column(type="integer")`

> Version numbers (not timestamps) should however be preferred as they can not potentially conflict in a highly concurrent environment, unlike timestamps where this is a possibility, depending on the resolution of the timestamp on the particular database platform. 
>   (source: Doctrine Documentation)

Comment: Looks good but unfortunately I can't find how to include `@version`... what does the `use` statement look like?

Comment: You can use either :
`use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Version;` then use the annotation @Version
or if you already have `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` call the annotation by `@ORM\Version`

Comment: cool, seems to work: `@Version @ORM\Column(type="datetime")`... you could put this line in your answer for quicker help for other, what do you think?